# Best way to downport funcrefs and partials from 8.2 to 7.4

Tags: vimscript

The 8.X version of vim introduced new possibilities for the `function()` command: the ability to
create `Partial` functions or to package funcrefs with arguments.

The difference of the `function()` help is shown below.

**version 7.4**

```
function({name})                    *function()* *E700*
        Return a |Funcref| variable that refers to function {name}.
        {name} can be a user defined function or an internal function.
```

**version 8.2**

```
                    *function()* *E700* *E922* *E923*
function({name} [, {arglist}] [, {dict}])
        Return a |Funcref| variable that refers to function {name}.
        {name} can be the name of a user defined function or an
        internal function.
[...]
        When {arglist} or {dict} is present this creates a partial.
        That means the argument list and/or the dictionary is stored in
        the Funcref and will be used when the Funcref is called.
```

I'm trying to downport to 7.X a 8.2 vimscript that make heavy use of such packaged-funcrefs/Partials.

Can someone point me in the right direction for v7.x design patterns that could mimic the new `function()` behavior?

Right now, all I can think of is to share the arguments array along the funcref but that would require to refactor all the logic around the code.

Any hint appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Vim 7.4 has been launch in August 2013. Just by curiosity could you tell us why you need to support a 10 years old version?

Comment: If you need partially-applied functions, you’ll have to simulate them. No way around that.

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble, that's what I feared, thanks!

Comment: @Vivian De Smedt: sadly, some of us are forced to work on rather old linux distributions to stay compatible with legacy software (SL7 with gvim 7.4 in my case). *sob*

Comment: Thanks I'm glad to hear that 7.4 is still in use in some old distributions.

Comment: It's possible to edit old code on a new editor. I don't know your exact situation but - from the top of my head - you should be able to remote into your legacy box or mount its hard drive on a current machine or use `rsync` to copy your changes there and similar ideas. Vim itself can edit remotely using netrw and `ssh`.

Comment: @Laurent' if you have access to compilers and can fetch the sources to Vim on the machine, you can consider installing Vim from source, perhaps inside your home directory (e.g. install it under `$HOME/.local` and then add `$HOME/.local/bin` to your `$PATH`), that might be a good way to get a recent/decent Vim on an old machine

Comment: Thanks for all your help :) FYI We already have a compiled-from-source 8.2 and 9.0 but all users aren't aware of it. I understand that 7.4 is too old to be considered a mandatory target for my plugin and will maybe halt the porting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer `function()` signature was introduced with Vim patch
`7.4.1559`.  It may have been applied to some Vim `7.4` builds.

Should you decide to port a script, with a view to touching
as few lines as possible, you may consider the following
approach:

- implement and encapsulate bespoke partial support in
  user-defined functions, i.e. `Call()` and `Function()`,
  whose signatures should match their namesake builtins;
- substitute user-defined names for builtin names whenever
  partials are passed around;
- resort to user-defined functions for `Funcref` invocation,
  e.g.,

  change:

  ```vim
  let b:Printer = function('printf', ['%s'])
  echo b:Printer('hello')
  ```

  to:

  ```vim
  let b:Printer = Function('printf', ['%s'])
  echo Call(b:Printer, ['hello'])
  ```
- review `Funcref`-related `type()` tests, if there are any.

For example, these definitions and test examples are valid
for base Vim 7.0 builds:

```
" Join line-breaks.
set cpoptions-=C

" (Note that the _dict_ parameter is not implemented.)
" Function({name} [, {arglist}])
" Function({func} [, {arglist}])
" Function({list} [, {arglist}])
function! Function(prefix, ...) abort
    return (a:0 > 0)
        \ ? type(a:prefix) == type([])
            \ ? [a:prefix[0], extend(deepcopy(a:prefix[1], 1),
                        \ deepcopy(a:000[0], 1))]
            \ : [a:prefix, deepcopy(a:000[0], 1)]
        \ : a:prefix
endfunction

" (Note that the _dict_ parameter is not implemented.)
" Call({name}, {arglist})
" Call({func}, {arglist})
" Call({list}, {arglist})
function! Call(prefix, args) range abort
    return type(a:prefix) == type([])
        \ ? call(a:prefix[0], extend(deepcopy(a:prefix[1], 1),
                        \ deepcopy(a:args, 1)))
        \ : call(a:prefix, a:args)
endfunction


""""
""""
"""" A FEW TEST EXAMPLES.
""""
""""

echo Call(Function('len'), [[""]]) == 1
echo Call(function('len'), [[""]]) == 1
echo call(Function('len'), [[""]]) == 1
echo call(function('len'), [[""]]) == 1

echo Call(Function('printf', ['%s %s', 'hello']), ['world']) == 'hello world'

function! PrettyPrinter(format) abort
    return Function('printf', [a:format])
endfunction

let b:pp_1 = Call('PrettyPrinter', ['%s, %s, %s, %s'])
let b:pp_2 = Function(b:pp_1, ['hello'])
let b:pp_3 = Function(b:pp_2, ['hello'])
let b:pp_4 = Function(b:pp_3, ['hello'])
echo Call(b:pp_4, ['hello']) == 'hello, hello, hello, hello'

let b:pf_1 = Function('printf', ['%s, %s, %s, %s'])
let b:pf_2 = Function(b:pf_1, ['hello'])
let b:pf_3 = Function(b:pf_2, ['hello'])
let b:pf_4 = Function(b:pf_3, ['hello'])
echo Call(b:pf_4, ['hello']) == 'hello, hello, hello, hello'


" C: x -> y = x
function! s:C(x, y) abort
    return a:x
endfunction

function! Constancy(value) abort
    return Function('s:C', [a:value])
endfunction

let b:const = Call('Constancy', [0])
echo Call(b:const, [1]) == 0
echo Call(b:const, [2]) == 0


" T: f -> y -> x = fxy
function! s:T(f, y, x) abort
    return call(a:f, [a:x, a:y])
endfunction

function! Mapper(func) abort
    return Function('s:T', ['map', a:func])
endfunction

let b:doubler = Call('Mapper', ['v:val * v:val'])
echo Call(b:doubler, [range(7)]) == [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]

let b:letterer = Call('Mapper', ['nr2char(v:val)'])
echo Call(b:letterer, [range(65, 65 + 3)]) == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks!